# How to stop a paperclip slipping off

Tags: stationery, office-supplies

Sometimes, when I'm organising notes and documents, I like to group them together and use paper clips to hold those groups together. When I start stacking those groups of documents on top of each other, 1/a few stacks' paperclips push off.

**How can I stop the paperclips from falling off the paper? Would I be best just to staple them together? I put them on exactly like the image below**

**To Clarify:** I want to know how to stop it when there are multiple stacks, not 1 big stack.

[image: Paper clip]

Comment: Please clarify whether your paper clip falls of a given huge paper stack, or due to multiple stacks stored on top of each other?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That does indeed happen just as you describe.  A staple would definitely solve the problem.

A few other options are paper clamps (shown below) or to use envelopes (large manilla) for groupings.

[image: Paper clamp]

Comment: And a battery? Weird

Comment: Disclaimer: picture is not mine! I think the battery is for scale.

Answer (score 1):

Paperclips are used for small stacks of paper. If you want to group together a larger stack of paper, I recommend the answer above, to use bulldog clips, as they clamp onto the papers as tight as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Ruff the surface of the paperclip to create more surface area or get rubber coated ones.
The problem with the first answer is that they don't stack well.

[image]
[image]